# I have a project which i want to deploy on Surge with GitHub Actions but every time i face this error when i push some modification on GitHub

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, github-actions, surge.sh

I don't know about the invalid user or password
[image]

```
name: Deploy Website

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    name: Deploying to surge
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - name: Install Surge
        run: npm install -g surge
      - name: Run surge
        run: surge ./ https://bootcamp_class01.surge.sh --token ${{ secrets.SURGE_TOKEN}}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm not an expert but the space after `${{` in the last `run` field looks suspicious.